# How to make the kendo tooltip content left justified

Tags: javascript, html, css, kendo-ui, tooltip

I have a kendo tooltip that is displayed when I hover over a row in a kendo grid.
The content of the tooltip has multiple lines.
The lines are displayed centered by default whereas I would like to have them displayed left justified.

```
    rowTable.kendoTooltip({
                               content: textToBeDisplayed,
                               position: "bottom"
                           });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override the `.k-tooltip-content` CSS class.

```
 .k-tooltip-content {
        text-align:left;
    }
```

See this [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8atpe7xb/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! that answers perfectly my question. I have though modified the kendo.common.min.css file for that and it worked.

Comment: Be aware that this will override the styles for all tooltips in your application. To not interfere with other tooltips, see **Sergey_T**'s answer.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who don't want to override the css class. I added "in-line" styling on the content.

```
.Content("<div style='text-align:left;'> " + myContent + "</div>")
```

Answer (score 1):

**Codingbadger**'s answer is correct, but it overrides styles for all tooltips that you have on a page.

Here is an example where styles are changed only for the specific tooltip: http://jsfiddle.net/NameGrey/d4b0ez4n/5/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#target").kendoTooltip({
    position: "right",
    width: "200px",
    content: "<div class='my-tooltip'>Tooltip content with <b>solid example</b></div>"
  });
});
```

Css:

```
.my-tooltip {
    text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```